# Replace element value in DOM

Tags: php, xml, replace

I want to save DOM tags value to exist XML, I found replace function but it is in js and I need the function in PHP

I tried `save` and `saveXML` function, but this didn't worked. I have tags in XML with colon "iaiext:auction_title". I used `getElement` and it's work good, next i cut title to 50 characters function work too, but how i can replace old title to this new title if i dont use path like simple_load_file. How to show in my script this path?

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('p.xml');
$i = 0;
$tytuly = $dom->getElementsByTagName('auction_title');
foreach ($tytuly as $tytul){

    $title = $tytul->nodeValue;
    $end_title = doTitleCut($title);
    //echo "<pre>";
    //echo($end_title);
    //echo "<pre>";
    $i = $i+1;
}
```

Comment: A good, complete, verifiable question will offer a minimal representative sample input string, then offer an exact expected output based on the input string and the processing logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop, you can update a particular nodes value the same way you fetch it - with `nodeValue`.  So in your loop, just update it each time...

```
$tytul->nodeValue = doTitleCut($title);
```

Then after your loop, you can just echo the new XML out using

```
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

or save it using

```
$dom->save("3.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the same basic API in PHP. However browsers implement more or other parts of the API. Here are 5 revisions of the API (DOM Level 1 to 4 and DOM LS). DOM 3 added a property to read/write the text content of a node: https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-textContent

The following example prefixes the titles:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<auctions>
  <auction_title>World!</auction_title>
  <auction_title>World &amp; Universe!</auction_title>
</auctions>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);

$titleNodes = $document->getElementsByTagName('auction_title');
foreach ($titleNodes as $titleNode) {
    $title = $titleNode->textContent;
    $titleNode->textContent = 'Hello '.$title;
}

echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<auctions> 
  <auction_title>Hello World!</auction_title> 
  <auction_title>Hello World &amp; Universe!</auction_title> 
</auctions>
```

PHPs `DOMNode::$nodeValue` implementation does not match the W3C API definition. It behaves the same as `DOMNode::$textContent` for reads and does not fully escape on write.